# Unable to login to the backend | Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter

Tags: magento2, backend

I've recently migrated a magento site (my first). After the migration I created an admin account using bash since I don't have access to the backend.

This is the command I ran to create an admin account. (not the actual values)

```
/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Abc@123456" --admin-email="test@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

But when I'm trying to log in to the backend it throws the below error.

```
There has been an error processing your request

Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> 
Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory ] of 
Magento\Security\Observer\AdminUserAuthenticateBefore class
```

Since i'm fairly new to magento environment I've no clue how to debug this issue. Please help me to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the user Admin already exist maybe?

Comment: no sir, i actually put my name there, this is just a sample command i used